# How to map prisma data model to a DTO in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, prisma

I am a newbie to the NestJS. I have a Prisma User model with token fields.

```
model User {
  id                 String    @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  firstName          String    @map("first_name") @db.VarChar(255)
  lastName           String    @map("last_name") @db.VarChar(255)
  email              String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  nationalityCode    String    @map("nationality_code") @db.VarChar(2)
  countryCode        String    @map("country_code") @db.VarChar(10)
  contactNumber      String    @map("contact_number") @db.VarChar(15)
  passportNumber     String?   @map("passport_number") @db.VarChar(9)
  nicNumber          String?   @map("nic_number") @db.VarChar(12)
  dateOfBirth        DateTime? @map("date_of_birth") @db.Date
  emailOtpId         String?   @map("email_otp_id") @db.Uuid
  emailOtp           EmailOtp? @relation("email_otps", fields: [emailOtpId], references: [id])
  emailVerified      Boolean   @default(false) @map("email_verified")
  emailOtpSentAt     DateTime? @map("email_otp_sent_at") @db.Timestamptz
  passwordResetOtpId String?   @map("password_reset_otp_id") @db.Uuid
  passwordResetOtp   EmailOtp? @relation("password_reset_otps", fields: [passwordResetOtpId], references: [id])
  googleToken        String?   @map("google_token") @db.VarChar(255)
  facebookToken      String?   @map("facebook_token") @db.VarChar(255)
  instagramToken     String?   @map("instagram_token") @db.VarChar(255)
  appleToken         String?   @map("apple_token") @db.VarChar(255)
  profilePictureKey  String?   @map("profile_picture_key") @db.VarChar(255)
  preferredLocaleId  String    @default("en") @map("preferred_locale_id") @db.VarChar(2)
  preferredLocale    Locale    @relation(fields: [preferredLocaleId], references: [code])
  createdAt          DateTime  @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt          DateTime  @updatedAt @map("updated_at")

  @@map("users")
}
```

I want to return a data model without the token fields when Get() API is callled. Following is my DTO without token fields.

```
export class UserDto {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string
    email: string
    nationalityCode: string
    countryCode: string
    contactNumber: string
    passportNumber?: string
    nicNumber?: string
    dateOfBirth?: Date
    profilePictureKey?: string
    preferredLocaleId: string
}
```

Have used plainToClass method in class-transformer in following way, but it didn't work. It still returns data with token fields.

```
return plainToClass(UserDto, this.userRepository.getUser(id));
```

Response =>

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "a51a171e-ca9e-4dd2-9a25-75f43d4a1cbf",
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "email": "test@gmail9.com",
        "nationalityCode": "US",
        "countryCode": "+1",
        "contactNumber": "(201)-867-5309",
        "passportNumber": null,
        "nicNumber": null,
        "dateOfBirth": null,
        "emailOtpId": null,
        "emailVerified": false,
        "emailOtpSentAt": null,
        "passwordResetOtpId": null,
        "googleToken": null,
        "facebookToken": null,
        "instagramToken": null,
        "appleToken": null,
        "profilePictureKey": null,
        "preferredLocaleId": "en",
        "createdAt": "2023-07-15T15:40:59.112Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-07-15T15:40:59.112Z"
    }
}
```

Appreciate, if you can help me to return data without token fields.

Answer (score 1):

If your repository don't return `User` model that generated by Prisma, so you can add `@Exclude()` to token fields to exclude those when it is transformed. (See more [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#skipping-specific-properties)).

In opposite, if you can't or don't want to update `User` model. you still config those fields excluded by `options` in class `plainToClass`. Options detail in [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/src/interfaces/class-transformer-options.interface.ts).

The below code is example:

```
plainToClass(UserDto, this.userRepository.getUser(id), { strategy: 'exposeAll', excludePrefixes: ['googleToken', 'facebookToken'] });
```

May be you must add list fields in `excludePrefixes` or in case your class have some fields with named such as `googleTokenABC` which I don't want to be excluded. Because as it's name, this option exclude fields by prefix, so you can add prefix `_` before all fields excluded.